# Traversing web page in javascript

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to iterate through a DOM tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714268/how-to-iterate-through-a-dom-tree)

Could you advise me how to write the following pseudocode in javascript?

```
for each child of <body>:
  if (tag.haschildren):
    for each tag.child:
       do some action;
```

thank you

Comment: The pseudo code will do some action on some tags twice, is that wanted?

Comment: @noiv11 It depends on what some_action will be.

Comment: No, whatever some_action is, it will be called more often than the amount of  tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var els = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
for (var i = 0, ii = els.length; i < ii; i++) {
  for (var j = 0, jj = els[i].childNodes.length; j < jj; j++) {
    action(els[i].childNodes[j]);
  }  
}
```

Comment: Can I traverse level by level? E.g. 1) <body> 2) first child Ch of body 3) go in this way to the leave nodes 4) traverse all leaves 5) one level up 6) to the leaves 7) up 8) etc.

Comment: @xralf yes and you can always write it yourself. It's a standard depth first tree traversal.

Comment: So I will write something like this? `var root = document.getElementsByTagName("body"); var subroot = root.childNodes; for (var i = 0, i < root.childNodes.length; i++) { if subroot[i].hasChilden godown() ; else process(subroot[i]); ...}` Is there a function testing that the node is leave?